# How to ref JSON schema definition of type array with anyOf definition in other files

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have a `jsonschema` definition `definition-1.json` like below. I have a property called `inputs` of type `array` which refers `anyOf` `definitions` like

```
"inputs": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stringParameter"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/numberParameter"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/booleanParameter"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/jsonParameter"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/fileParameter"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then the parameter `definitions` defined like below in the same `jsonschema` `definition-1.json`

```
"definitions": {
    "stringParameter": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "description",
        "datatype"
      ]
   }
 ...
}
```

Now I want to reference this parameter `definitions` in my other schema `dummy-1.json` like below

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "dummy-1.json",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "definition_data"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "definition_data": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "inputs"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "type": "array",
            "inputs": {
              "items": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "prop1": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/stringParameter"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "prop2": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/numberParameter"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "definition_data": {
          "$ref": "definition-1.json"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This doesn't looks like working. `prop1` will validate successfully for any properties part of other parameter definition too , even though in `dummy-1.json` I explicitly referred `#/definitions/stringParameter` .
I can understand `inputs` in `definition-1.json` accepts `anyOf` all parameter `definitions`. But want to know how we can achieve 1:1 parameter definition mapping for `dummy-1.json` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to refer from `dummy-1.json` to subschemas defined in `definitions-1.json`. To do that, you have to specify the URI of `definition-1.json` and append the pointer of the subschema in it, like:

`dummy-1.json`:

```json
{
  "$ref": "uri-of-definitions-1.json#/definitions/stringParameter"
}
```

Note that the URI to be set is quite specific to the json schema library you are using. Usually an absolute `https://` URL works, but it isn't always convenient to  work with. Maybe a relative path can work for you as well (like `./definition-1.json#/definitions/stringParameter`)